# How to calculate value based on previous rows and store it in new column/table on fly or periodicaly?

Tags: sql, clickhouse, materialized-views

I'm using Clickhouse to store `stocks` data for each of 50.000.000+ products

```sql
create table stocks
(
    check_id UUID,
    product_id Int32,
    size_id UInt32,
    size_name Nullable(String),
    size_original_name Nullable(String),
    price_retail UInt32,
    price_discount UInt32,
    price_total UInt32,
    quantity UInt16,
    warehouse_id UInt32,
    created_at DateTime default now()
)
engine = MergeTree PRIMARY KEY (check_id, product_id, size_id, warehouse_id)
ORDER BY (check_id, product_id, size_id, warehouse_id, created_at)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

Example data:

```
INSERT INTO default.stocks (check_id, product_id, size_id, size_name, size_original_name, price_retail, price_discount, price_total, quantity, warehouse_id, created_at) VALUES ('0d3b10c0-c831-4d4f-8000-0011647feeee', 56519877, 103180735, '', '0', 590, 0, 590, 8, 146666, '2023-05-02 01:00:00');
INSERT INTO default.stocks (check_id, product_id, size_id, size_name, size_original_name, price_retail, price_discount, price_total, quantity, warehouse_id, created_at) VALUES ('21303340-d2ad-4ed5-8000-00117981cccc', 119518232, 212006721, '', '0', 12558, 40, 7534, 2, 119261, '2023-05-02 01:00:00');
INSERT INTO default.stocks (check_id, product_id, size_id, size_name, size_original_name, price_retail, price_discount, price_total, quantity, warehouse_id, created_at) VALUES ('0d3b10c0-c831-4d4f-8000-0011647fe692', 56519877, 103180735, '', '0', 590, 0, 590, 10, 146666, '2023-05-01 19:22:31');
INSERT INTO default.stocks (check_id, product_id, size_id, size_name, size_original_name, price_retail, price_discount, price_total, quantity, warehouse_id, created_at) VALUES ('21303340-d2ad-4ed5-8000-00117981c344', 119518232, 212006721, '', '0', 12558, 40, 7534, 4, 119261, '2023-05-01 19:22:31');
```

[image]

I want to calculate difference between current quantity and latest before `order by created_at DESC` per `product_id, size_id, warehouse_id` and store this value in new column or table `orders`

So i decided to create a Materialized View with `POPULATE`

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW orders_mv POPULATE AS
SELECT check_id, product_id, size_id, warehouse_id, orders, created_at
FROM (SELECT check_id,
             product_id,
             size_id,
             warehouse_id,
             quantity,
             leadInFrame(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, size_id, warehouse_id ORDER BY product_id ASC, size_id ASC, warehouse_id ASC, created_at DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) - quantity AS orders,
             row_number()          OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, size_id, warehouse_id ORDER BY product_id ASC, size_id ASC, warehouse_id ASC, created_at ASC) AS rn,
             created_at
      FROM stocks)
WHERE rn > 1
  AND orders > 0
```

And yes, it works, but only for POPULATED data. It was fast enough (30sec for over 100.000.000 rows).

But If i try to insert new batch of data, it would not work, because i have no access to source table and i can't calculate `orders` value using `leadInFrame` function without previous data. (Or i don't know how to make it)

[Docs](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/view#materialized-view)

> A materialized view is implemented as follows: when inserting data to the table specified in SELECT, **part of the inserted data** is converted by this SELECT query, and the result is inserted in the view.

I'm stuck. I don't know how to calculate `orders` on fly or periodicaly and store it in separate table or inside source table with new column `orders`.

I also tried to precalculate this value inside my app before insertion, but it works so slow due to preSELECT of latest `stocks` data for over 25.000 products per second.

It was a bad idea, but i tried to make `SELECT` inside `INSERT INTO`

```sql
INSERT INTO default.stocks (
  check_id, product_id, size_id, size_name, 
  size_original_name, price_retail, 
  price_discount, price_total, orders, 
  quantity, warehouse_id, created_at
) 
SELECT 
  '4fabf564-9180-454c-8000-00003e51686d' as check_id, 
  132483979 as product_id, 
  227949094 as size_id, 
  '42' as size_name, 
  'S' as size_original_name, 
  5600 as price_retail, 
  50 as price_discount, 
  2800 as price_total, 
  (
    SELECT 
      quantity - 5 as orders 
    FROM 
      default.stocks_bak PREWHERE check_id = (
        SELECT 
          check_id 
        FROM 
          default.stocks_check_ids 
        WHERE 
          product_id = 31 
        ORDER BY 
          created_at ASC 
        LIMIT 
          1
      ) AND size_id = 69059711 
      AND warehouse_id = 117986
  ) as orders, 
  4 as quantity, 
  208818 as warehouse_id, 
  now() as created_at;
```

It works for single insertion (but i need to insert over 25.000 per second) So i tried to make insertion with multiple values using `UNION ALL` like this

```sql
INSERT INTO default.stocks (
  check_id, product_id, size_id, size_name, 
  size_original_name, price_retail, 
  price_discount, price_total, orders, 
  quantity, warehouse_id, created_at
) 
SELECT 
  '4fabf564-9180-454c-8000-00003e51686d' AS check_id, 
  132483979 AS product_id, 
  227949094 AS size_id, 
  '42' AS size_name, 
  'S' AS size_original_name, 
  5600 AS price_retail, 
  50 AS price_discount, 
  2800 AS price_total, 
  (
    SELECT 
      quantity - 5 AS orders 
    FROM 
      default.stocks_bak PREWHERE (
        check_id = (
          SELECT 
            check_id 
          FROM 
            default.stocks_check_ids 
          WHERE 
            product_id = 31 
          ORDER BY 
            created_at ASC 
          LIMIT 
            1
        )
      ) AND (size_id = 69059711) 
      AND (warehouse_id = 117986)
  ) AS orders, 
  4 AS quantity, 
  208818 AS warehouse_id, 
  '2023-05-01 03:01:08' AS created_at 
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
...
...
...
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
...
...
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  '4fabf564-9180-454c-8000-00003e51686d' AS check_id, 
  132483979 AS product_id, 
  227949094 AS size_id, 
  '42' AS size_name, 
  'S' AS size_original_name, 
  5600 AS price_retail, 
  50 AS price_discount, 
  2800 AS price_total, 
  (
    SELECT 
      quantity - 5 AS orders 
    FROM 
      default.stocks_bak PREWHERE (
        check_id = (
          SELECT 
            check_id 
          FROM 
            default.stocks_check_ids 
          WHERE 
            product_id = 31 
          ORDER BY 
            created_at ASC 
          LIMIT 
            1
        )
      ) AND (size_id = 69059711) 
      AND (warehouse_id = 117986)
  ) AS orders, 
  4 AS quantity, 
  208818 AS warehouse_id, 
  '2023-05-01 03:01:08' AS created_at
```

And of course it can't handle so much nested queries. So i get something like `max_ast` error (can't remember exact error name)

I believe that i can make it using Materialized View or with another Clickhouse functionality, but i'm stuck.

Comment: There is no magic in this universe. Current MatView is unable to provide this. https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf Some day refresheable MatView (scheduled) will able to do it.

Comment: Only adhoc select queries,  or cron (periodical recalculation).